# Database Lessons

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am almost done my Windows 7 app, this is my first time creating apps for mobile devices and I really need some help on what database to use for Windows phone and where are the best websites or possibly books for database connections such as MySQL or SQL. Please Help

Comment: This falls into the realm of 'asking for opinions' instead of 'asking for an answer to a technical question'. Opinions are generally outside the domain of Stack Overflow. Start somewhere (do a web search) and when you run into a wall come here and we'll help you over it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use mango aka windows phone 7.1, the easiest way is to go for the [built in local database](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/08/01/windows-phone-7-using-local-database-for-application.aspx?Redirected=true)